# Suppressing key events

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Windows forms we have suppressing key events to re-assign functionality.
Currently i'm developing on asp.net project where i need to suppress keys like `Alt+F4` ,`Alt+Space` ,`Alt+l` etc.

Is there a way to suppress keyboard events in `Asp.net`?

Comment: Suppress Alt+F4 as in you don't want the browser to close if someone presses them?

Comment: Yes,like alt+l ,alt + space key

Comment: XY problem. Explain your original problem. You're probably looking for [Kiosk mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software).

Comment: These assignments are done to override existing shortcuts in the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where we want to disable the enter key from generating a postback

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
   onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

You can do it also in your codebehind c# class like this

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");
```

Of course you need to get the corresponding codes for each key you want to deactivate. [Here is a reference for instance](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/keyboard/kbdscancode.html)

Comment: could you post a specific one regarding 'Alt+f4',asp.net?

Comment: sure. On what specific UI web control are you planning to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using : [keyPress Event Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Eg :Alt+F4.

```
if (evt.altKey && evt.keyCode==115) {
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

here is an list of Keycode you can make use : [Key Code](http://www.expandinghead.net/keycode.html)